# Почему выводит ничего вместо двойки в данном примере кода?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var check=$("#timer").val();
   
alert(check);
```

```html
<p id="timer" >2</p>
```

Comment: Метод val() используется для получения значения из атрибута value для input, select, textarea.

Comment: `$("#timer").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно так

```
var check=$("#timer").text();

alert(check);
```